# Segmentation Fault || Access Violation Writing location

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, fault

I want to insert a Node in a doubly linked list. I'm passed in the position, the new coefficient of the Polynomial and its power. I have no compile errors, but I get a Segmentation fault in linux (g++) and an Access Violation Writing Location when I run it with Visual Studio.

Unhandled exception at 0x00bd20ba in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdd9.

```
void Polynomial::insert( Term *pos, double newCoefficient, int power )
{
    Term *newTerm = new Term; // create a new node to insert

    // Link the new node to previous and next, given the position
    newTerm->prev = pos->prev;
    newTerm->next = pos;
    newTerm->prev->next = newTerm; // Here's where I'm getting the error
    newTerm->next->prev = newTerm;

    // change the coefficient and power
    newTerm->coefficient = newCoefficient;
    newTerm->power = power;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and How do I fix this?

Comment: The address `0xcdcdcdd9` has debug-filler written all over it. validate your inputs before dereferencing them (or assigning them for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `pos` is the first node, then `pos->prev` must be `NULL`. In that case, the statement `newTerm->prev->next = newTerm;` would crash, because there's no such thing as `NULL->next`!

You should check explicitly if `pos` is the first node in the list, and place `newNode` accordingly.

```
// Link the new node to previous and next, given the position
newTerm->prev = pos->prev;
newTerm->next = pos;
if(pos->prev) newTerm->prev->next = newTerm;
newTerm->next->prev = newTerm;
```

Comment: Thank You. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

`pos->prev` is likely to be NULL or uninitialized. You must validate your inputs before using them...

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether in any instance of executing the program whether pos can be the first node in the list. If it is, then it will cause a segmentation fault as you are accessing a member of the NULL pointer.

Always consider extreme cases when you are programming and make sure you have put required conditionals for them.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you implement a doubly linked list by yourself. You could define a `struct` or `class` which contains `coefficient` and `power` members and use it as the value type of `std::list`. This would give you lots of list operations (such as inserting and deleting elements) for free. As a bonus, `std::list` comes with proper iterators (instead of position pointers) to be used in standard algorithms.

Since the rest of your `Polynomial` class is missing (it is a class, not just a namespace, is it?) it is difficult to provide more concrete help.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault  generally happens when you try to dereference a NULL pointer.

It is considered a good practice to use NULL checks while dealing with pointers.In this case it seems that pos->prev is NULL which is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Other bad addresses can cause this too, not just null pointers.